# Find Number of visitors for a site in ASP.NET MVC using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, httpapplication, httpapplicationstate

I am trying to find number of visitors for a site using Application.

My Global.asax.cs looks like this:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

        //Added for version tracking
        Application["ActiveUsers"] = 0;
    }
```

And my Controller I added following code:

```
string i =  Application["ActiveUsers"].ToString();
```

But I am getting a error "***Application' does not exist in the current context***" .

Am I missing any namespace or is Application doesn't work in Controller level.(I don't see error in Golbal.asax.cs)

Thanks.

Comment: It's `MvcApplication` and I don't think you can even do that.

Comment: This would not work on a load balanced server, and remember that IIS will recycle your domain every 28 hours or so (sometimes even more frequently).   You should be storing value this in a database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access that via:

```
int i = HttpContext.Application["ActiveUsers"] as int;
```